# Перебрать массив объектов и получить значение ключа

Tags: filter, массивы, объекты, javascript

Что-то неправильно делаю.

Есть массив:

```
var arr = [ 
       { key: 'слово', value: 'значение1' },
       { key: 'слово2', value: 'значение2' },
       { key: 'слово3', value: 'значение3' }
    ]
```

Нужно по слову "слово2" получить значение value (значение2).

Пробую так:

```
function getValue(array, value) {
    var obj = array.filter(function(arr, i){
        return arr.key === value ? arr.value : '';
    });
    return obj;
}

console.log(getValue(arr, "слово2"));
```

Получаю массив с одним объектом, а нужно получить только значение value.

Comment: Уточните для себя, что делает с массивом метод [`filter()`](http://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#filter). Вашу задачу можно решить и с ним, и с методом [`reduce`](http://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#reduce-reduceright), если известно, что искомый элемент не больше одного раза встречается в исходном масиве.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function getValues(array, search) {
  var values = [];

  array.forEach(function(values, item){
    (item.key === search) && values.push(item.value);
  });

  return values;
}
```

---

```
function getValues(array, search) {
  return array
    .filter(function(values, item){
      return (item.key === search)
    })
    .map(function (item) {
      return item.value;
    });
}
```

---

```
function getValues(array, search) {
    return array.reduce(function(values, item){
        (item.key === search) && values.push(item.value);
        return values;
    }, []);
}
```

---

**UPD**: Если нужно только одно значение, то нечего выдумывать:

```
function getValue(array, search) {
  var i = array.length;
  while (i--) {
      if (array[i].key === search) {
         return array[i].value;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: ОП хочет не массив, а единственное значение на выходе.

Comment: Ну тогда ему `for/while` + `break` в руки.

Comment: @MasterAlex, а-ха-ха, хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/azttrwxs/ я бы это сделал вот так

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с `reduce`:

```
function getValue( A, K) {
    return A.reduce(
        function( prev, item) {
          return ( !prev  &&  item.key == K) ? item.value : prev;
        },
        false
    );
}
```

[попробовать](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/vfffcted/)

Comment: @sergiks, а удовлетворите праздное любопытство. Объясните, чем тривиальная и наверное общепонятная запись

      for (var i = 0, len = A.length; i < len; i++)
        if (A[i].key === K) 
          return A[i].value;
      return false;  

хуже, чем `A.reduce(...)` или `A.forEach(...)` и т.п., которых полно в ответах.

Comment: @avp, хуже — уж тем, что работает на IE8, а `reduce()` прекрасный геноцид против старых ИЕ : )

По перформансу `reduce()` с треском проигрывает обычному `for(){}`, как показал наскоро проделанный [тест](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/vfffcted/1/)  — у меня в FF на маке 295ms `reduce` против всего 32ms `for`.

Мне же просто симпатичен синтакс и использование нативной функции JS.

Answer (score 0):

var arr = [

```
   { key: 'слово', value: 'значение1' },  
   { key: 'слово2', value: 'значение2' },  
   { key: 'слово3', value: 'значение3' }
]
```

**Скажите, а как заменить значение объекта в массиве по key**? Пример:
=> update(слово2, значение4)

var arr = [

```
   { key: 'слово', value: 'значение1' }   
   { key: 'слово2', value: 'значение4' }, 
   { key: 'слово3', value: 'значение3' }
]
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/azttrwxs/1/ можно вот так