# обработка обьекта(вида ассоциативного массива) js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Уже просмотрел много информации на данную тему, но никак не могу решить свою маленькую проблему.

Цель: получить данные `k => v`

Возвращается объект вида массива из php

```
if(isset($_POST['getComment'])) {

    echo json_encode(array(
        array(  "name" => "Viktor",
                'comment' => "коментарий Виктора"),
        array(  "name" => "Петя",
                "comment" => "коментарий Пети")
        ));
}
```

Пытаюсь перебрать его в js

```
 function createFunc(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        // $('body').append("<div id='com'></div>");
        for (var i in data) {
            for (var j in data[i]) {
                $('#com').append($("<p> " + i +" : " + j + " : "+ data[i][j] + "</p>"));

            }
        }
    }
```

Нужно обратиться к ключу одного массива - получить значения по отдельности - name такое

Дальше значение `comment`. И так с каждым массивом по иерархии. а выодит получить все значения сразу. все значения во всех массивах.

Я прекрасно понимаю, что постановка вопроса, как и сам вопрос плевый. 
Но я не могу разобраться.
Заранее спасибо всем кто уделил время данной проблеме.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
        .done(function(r) {

            //v1
            for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                $('.res').append(JSON.stringify(r[i]) + '<br>');
            }

            //v2
            for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                for (var variable in r[i]) {
                    $('.res').append(variable + ": " + r[i][variable] + "<br>");
                }
            }
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });

});
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, но это совсем иное. Выводит Каждый символ ключа и значения отдельно с индексом массива, к которому принадлежит/ и символы в юникоде

Comment: @mydls1 вариант 2 - это и есть перебор всех ваших значений `k => v`

Comment: Наверно я не корректно изьяснил свои мысли. После тщательного поиска на сайте я нашел, то что меня интересовало , правда еще немного доработать надо... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/360791/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0